# Can a high power leaf blower damage my house?

Tags: windows, siding, blower, wind

I get a lot of bugs that accumulate along the side of my house, under the soffits, around the ledges of single-hung windows, etc.

I would like to try a leaf blower to blow all these junk off.

Some leaf blowers can reach speeds of 180 MPH - higher than a category 5 hurricane.

Can I therefore do damage to my sidings or windows if I use such a leaf blower against the side of my house?

Comment: If the bugs are holding onto your house tighter than your siding is you probably needed to replace it anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that those 180mph ratings are in ideal conditions, and likely not able to be reached in normal use.  Just use the blower from a suitable distance (i.e. not with the nozzle right up next to the siding) and you should be fine.  And also blow in a direction that doesn't try and go underneath the siding that might cause it to pop out.  Most blowers also have adjustable power, so just use enough power to clean the bugs and debris away, and there shouldn't be any damage.

Comment: I'd guess those 180MPH ratings are marketing fantasies. Who is actually going to test them? But yeah, this answer is quite correct.